# MDAC with Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have Windows Server 2008 and Sql Server 2005.I am running a mobile application on Windows Mobile 5.0.My mobile application use SQL Server 2005 Mobile edition as device database and I use RDA version 3.0 to access data from server.It works fine with Windows Server 2003 but with Windows Server 2008 it throws an error during "RDA.Pull" method asking me to install MDAC version 2.8 or later.
 I tried to install MDAC2.8 and it gets installed but still I get the same error.

Please suggest...

~Agesh

Answer (score 1):

MDAC is not officially available for Server 2008.  If you search this web site you may be able to find some workarounds.  For Server 2008, MDAC has been superseded by WDAC.

According to: [Microsoft's Road Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx)...

***Windows Data Access Components (WDAC)**: MDAC changed its name to WDAC - "Windows Data Access Components" since Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. WDAC is included as part of the operating system and is not available separately for redistribution. Serviceability for WDAC is subject to the life cycle of the operating system.

32-bit and 64-bit versions of WDAC are released with the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Windows operating systems, respectively.*